# VBA Using Access Database Not Working on Some Computers

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection

I'm having a bit of trouble with a VBA program that i have inhertied from a co-worker (who has since left). The VBA program uses an Access Database to retrieve information and the connection seems to be a bit flaky. Some computers it will work fine on and others not, within the same company.
The Access Database Engine 2010 has been installed on all the PCs to ensure all drivers are correct. The below is the connection string used

```
'Open Database connection for Access 2007
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & sDBFullName & ";" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & cPassword & ";Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open
```

I know the Connection used is old but has been working fine. I also can't find a connection for OLEDB versions after V12.

I would like a bit of advice which is the best way to go with VBA and Access. The company has updated to Office 2016, but not all PC's have Access. I have done a bit with VB.NET but can't work out how to back-translate it to VBA - if it can be.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/     .... _reports of problems with password_  mentioned near top of page

Comment: What do you mean by "VBA program"?  I ask because VBA must be hosted inside another application... usually an MS Office application.  An Access database can indeed be opened outside of Access--for example in Excel using VBA--but unless you indicate the exact context, I would assume that the "VBA program" is hosted by Access itself. Although ADO/OLEDB is newer and can be used to connect, Access itself still uses DOA as the default data access library. Understanding why your program uses ADODB (instead of DAO) could help answer the question. Does the program use Access forms and reports?

Comment: Could the program that 'uses an Access database' be VB6?

Comment: The VBA Program sits inside a Drafting Application called "MicroStation". Microstation uses the Access Database to retrieve information.

Comment: Can the runtime version of Access get installed on those computers that don't have it? If you have that, you can use the `Access.Application` object as a workaround to create an `ADO` connection that isn't version-specific.

Comment: Woops, pressed enter to soon. To add to my comment above......All forms are VBA forms, with information populated by variants filled from Access. So basically the only thing that access is being used for is data storage. The Database is also password protected if that matters (I only mention as most of the connection strings i have found require a username and password)

Comment: I suggest wrapping any "flaky" VBA code with proper error handling to catch and log errors.  Start with the connection code you show.  There are various ways to do this, but the basics would be to add something like `On Error Resume Next` at the start, then after conn.Open add `If err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description` to print the error in the VBA IDE Immediate window.

Comment: I have been able to debug the code on PC's that do now work and it always fails at the "conn.open" stating that the Access Database Library 14.0 is not registered (something along those lines). I know that the driver is written for 12.0 but it has never had an issue before and it still works sometimes

Comment: The "Access Database Library" does not refer to the same thing as the OLEDB provider version.  My guess is that the errors and version references are not necessarily due to the ACE OLEDB driver version, but rather than references in the VBA project -- accessible from the VBA IDE menu Tools | References.  Could this also be a problem between 32-bit and 64-bit versions?

Comment: I see that the question really asks for advise about VBA, Access and VB.Net, but honestly that kind of advise may be off topic for Stack Overflow. That's why the tendency has been to focus on helping debugging specific problems. If you want a useful answer I suggest updating your question with more details about Office versions, MicroStation version, VBA references along with more precise error details.  It would be prudent to get exact numbers and errors from multiple machines, not just general approximates.  Is there one or multiple "development" systems?  What versions do they have? Etc.

Comment: I have been doing some more digging on this and cannot find anything to help me. I have contacted the IT department who can confirm that the all Office versions are 32-bit 2016. All PC's are 64-bit Windows 7 or 10. There are no other differences that anyone can see with the computers. I am happy to redo the Access - VBA  connection, but having trouble finding out what's best to use. Most of the articles i have found use the same connection string, or use the DAO, but some say that is not as good as the OLEDB i have tried to use. Can anyone please shed some light on this for me please?